# Google earth image asset (does not exist or caller does not have access)

Tags: javascript, google-earth, google-earth-engine, google-earth-plugin

I am replicating this project : https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.20210497

And I was updating their data. However, I cannot even load the images.
I wonder what shall I do?

> wetland_riparian_1000: Layer error: Image.load: Image asset
> 'USGS/NLCD/NLCD2019' not found (does not exist or caller does not have
> access).

This is my current code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/df54d27dfa00fccb187a91602e3d82bb

I was expecting a successful run and giving the excel files as its data in 2016.
But always show error.
I am a beginner and I wonder if we have to really upload the files or just use the existing data file? What do you think?